# Sinch SMS verification SINVerificationErrorDomain Code=6 No route to destination

Tags: sinch

```
NSError *parseError = nil;
id<SINPhoneNumber> phoneNumber = [SINPhoneNumberUtil() parse:telephone
                                               defaultRegion:@"MX"
                                                       error:&parseError];

NSString *phoneNumberInE164 = [SINPhoneNumberUtil() formatNumber:phoneNumber
                                                          format:SINPhoneNumberFormatE164];

id<SINVerification> verification = [SINVerification SMSVerificationWithApplicationKey:SINCH_API_KEY
                                                                          phoneNumber:phoneNumberInE164];

[verification initiateWithCompletionHandler:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
    if (success) {
        NSLog(@"sucess");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"error : %@", error.description);
    }
}];
```

This is the error message:

> Error Domain=SINVerificationErrorDomain Code=6 "No route to destination." UserInfo={SINErrorReference=A:SINCH_API_KEY_3xgIxZ48c0yRxvHzfCo0ng, SINHTTPStatusCode=422, NSLocalizedDescription=No route to destination., NSUnderlyingError=0x1360c7020 {Error Domain=SINVerificationServiceErrorDomain Code=42201 "No route to destination." UserInfo={SINErrorReference=A:SINCH_API_KEY_3xgIxZ48c0yRxvHzfCo0ng, NSLocalizedDescription=No route to destination., SINHTTPStatusCode=422}}}

I am sure that my phone number and app key is correct. I have set *dashboard->verification>public*. Any idea?

Comment: Do you still have the problem, if so can you mail support@sinch.com with that particular number you are trying to verify. There is not generic error so tis likely a problem with that number

Comment: thanks

I contacted support and they fixed my problem :)

Answer (score 0):

The Sinch Verification API seems to be offline. I have tested with the JavaScript SDK and the REST API. Each result is the same when attempting to create a verification.

The HTTP status code is 422. This typically means the server cannot execute the instructions sent in the JSON. A likely cause would be a breaking change to the server code was done without updating the SDKs or API documentation.

I have sent a message to them with a link to this ticket.

Comment: The error in the JS SDK is as follows.

{"name":"SinchError","domain":7,"code":7002,"response":"{\"errorCode\":42201,\"message\":\"No route to destination.\",\"reference\":\"A:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\"}

Answer (score 0):

It was a temporary service disruption

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation:

```
//client side
SINVerificationErrorInvalidInput   = 1,
SINVerificationErrorIncorrectCode  = 2, //code doesn't match
SINVerificationErrorCalloutFailure = 3,
SINVerificationErrorTimeout        = 4,
SINVerificationErrorCancelled      = 5,

// Sinch backend service error
SINVerificationErrorServiceError   = 6
```

`SINVerificationErrorServiceError` should be reported to and handled by Sinch team

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this".

Comment: Although this code may help to solve the problem, it doesn't explain _why_ and/or _how_ it answers the question. Providing this additional context  would significantly improve its long-term educational value. Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, including what limitations and assumptions apply.